# When was this fabric made

Tags: fabric

This came from an estate sale and I plan on making a skirt from it to sell on Etsy. It's cotton & has no markings indicating maker or date. Anyone seen it & know when it's from?[image]

Comment: I know some designs are unique enough famous  enough to be identifiable without any further details, but do you have any reason to suspect this is such a design?

Comment: Even though this fabric is meant to be used in a handmade product, this question seems more like a manufacturer or artist identification question than any direct application, which doesn't really suit our scope.

Answer (score 1):

The cloth appears to be printed for a run of calendar tea towels, circa late 1960's to the late 1970's.  I notice, for example, that September 1st fell upon a Thursday in the year that the cloth was printed, so there should your quest begin...  start your search engines!

Comment: Good catch @Ferrox Glideh!

Comment: Unh, on second glance, it appears that every month began on a Thursday,  This indicates that the designs were being knocked off by people who do not care for scientifically useful tea towels.  This is just getting deeper and deeper.

Comment: Evil unscientific tea towel manufacturers...